# Develop OpenCL application without GPU support on Laptop?

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I am new to OpenCL and want to develop a portable hardware independent OpenCL application.
I have ATI Radeon 7670m on my laptop which has OpenCL 1.1 support as per official [website](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/7000m/7500m-7600m/Pages/radeon-7500m-7600m.aspx#2).
However this GPU is not listed on the APP SDK system requirements [site](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/).
I am interested in using OpenCL for developing only for GPU and not for CPU.
So is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You have a GPU capable of OpenCL, you have the SDK, what exactly is your problem? You can simply start using it! The SDK/code will not say "hey, this GPU is unknown, I will not use it". In fact you can use AMD SDK in nVIDIA or Intel devices.

Comment: @DarkZeros thanks for your reply. Well if that is the case then why have they listed those devices as system requirements. Also it says that it requires the latest Catalyst Control Centre. nVIDIA devices wouldnt obviously have CCC. So as per your sugesstion does this mean that the information is old/incorrect?

Comment: Those are not "requirement" are more a guide line. If your GPU supports it, then you can use it, even if the website does not say it explicitly.

Comment: ok... AMD confused me silly :P Can you make that an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, information on site is outdated. 7670 is OpenCL-compatible for sure. In fact, almost all cards of 5xxx series & newer can run OpenCL.

Comment: 7670M supports OpenCL 1.1 and OpenGL 4.2 but @Cool_Coder needs other information. He wants develop with OpenCL only for GPU.

Comment: Don't understand. TS wanted to develop gpgpu application. Headers and libraries are presented, card is compatible - no obstacles.

Comment: With OpenCL you can choose a Context. OpenCL works (creating memory, compiling and running programs) within this context. A context can have more devices/peripherals, such as CPU o GPU devices. You can set a device's context with CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU or CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan as I mentioned in the question I am aware that my GPU is OpenCL 1.1 capable. My question is whether I can develop OpenCL application on it? This is because AMD website says I cannot. Can you please clarify my doubt? Thanks...

Comment: Yes, you can develop. The most fresh standard is 1.2, but OpenCL 1.1 will do too. Many cards are limited by v 1.1 support, so this version is wide-spread.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan The AMD APP SDK system requirements page is not outdated.  The first paragraph on that page makes it clear that the hardware and software listed there is just the combinations tested by AMD's quality assurance team.  Paragraph 2 makes it clear that other combinations may also work.  What the OP needs for development is the C/C++ header files and libOpenCL.a (Linux) or OpenCL.lib (Windows).  Those will work fine on all devices in the AMD OpenCL platform (i.e. the OP's GPU).  What might not work is the examples in the SDK if they rely on OpenCL C 1.2 features.

Comment: Well, I made a guess, not statement. But, anyway, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

With OpenCL Context you can choose which device use for development (for example, CPU or GPU devices), in your case **CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU**:

```
cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, cprops, NULL, NULL, &err);
```

For example, from official AMD documentation:

```
int main(void)
{
    cl_int err;
    cl::vector< cl::Platform > platformList;
    cl::Platform::get(&platformList);
    checkErr(platformList.size()!=0 ? CL_SUCCESS : -1, "cl::Platform::get");
    std::cerr << "Platform number is: " << platformList.size() << std::endl;std::string platformVendor;
    platformList[0].getInfo((cl_platform_info)CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, &platformVendor);
    std::cerr << "Platform is by: " << platformVendor << "\n";
    cl_context_properties cprops[3] = {CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platformList[0])(), 0};
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, cprops, NULL, NULL, &err);
    checkErr(err, "Conext::Context()"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. My confusion was regarding SDK availability for my hardware. Can I use AMD SDK on say nVIDIA hardware for OpenCL development? If so then there should not be any problem on my hardware also. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You hardware it's ok. Read this topic: http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/162244 on AMD Developer Central Forum.

Comment: @Cool_Coder You go ahead with AMD App SDK for your hardware, it should certainly find your device. You can choose any SDK (intel, AMD or NVIDIA) regardless of the Hardware, Only thing you will not able to get in cross choosing is additional extension specific to hardware provided by specific Vendor.

Comment: Thanks Sagar that helped a lot.