# OpenMP "for" in realtime audio processing

Tags: openmp

I'm trying to use OpenMP to get some performance for realtime audio processing. I took an algorithm looking like this:

```
preparation
for (int I=0; I<1024; I++)
    something quite demanding
finalization
```

When not parallelized, it took about 3% of CPU according to the system meter. Now, if I parallelized the main loop, OMP used 8 threads (4 core i7 with hyperthreading), the main thread consumption went down to 2%, so the response was 33% faster, but the system performance meter started showing 100% (!!) overall system response, all cores fully loaded.

That looks like the threads were doing a lot of "nothing taking CPU" even during the waiting for next audio data request. Any ideas what that could be? The fact that the response was 33% faster is nice, but assuming there may be many similar processors running at the same moment, 100% CPU usage is just not usable. Perhaps OMP threads were actively waiting for more tasks?

I'm using MSVC 2013.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the details (code) on how you are parallelizing that loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the threads are spinning (waiting at the barrier) for the next iteration. You can control this behavior with OMP_WAIT_POLICY, and there was already a question on how to do this for [MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748066/how-can-microsofts-openmp-spinlock-time-be-controlled).

I should warn you that if you change the policy to PASSIVE, the other threads may be slow to wake back up to do work and this may introduce delay or jitter to your computation. If the processing is running acceptably fast on one thread, I would keep using only one thread to guarantee real-time.